# Como fazer linked server com banco Oracle para SQL Server 2008 (e considerando conexão VPN)?

Tags: sql, oracle, vpn, linked-server

Estou precisando criar uma conexão Linked Server para o banco SQL Server 2008 do meu cliente. Esse Linked Server será com um banco Oracle.

O meu banco SQL Server 2008 se encontra em um servidor próprio do meu cliente. Já o banco Oracle se encontra em um outro servidor remoto. Talvez pra acessar esse servidor, eu seja obrigado antes a fazer uma conexão ao VPN da máquina onde está esse banco Oracle.

Alguém sabe me informar como eu faço essa conexão linked server a um banco Oracle? Encontrei esse código abaixo de exemplo, que necessita do IP, nome do banco, login e senha:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'DBMV',
@srvproduct = 'Oracle',
@provider = 'OraOLEDB.Oracle',
@datasrc = '(DESCRIPTION=ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.0.65)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dbmv)))'
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@rmtsrvname = 'DBMV',
@useself = 'FALSE',
@rmtuser = 'leomar',
@rmtpassword = 'leomar123'
GO
```

Mas eu queria saber se esse exemplo funciona, se existe outra forma e se dentro dessa conexão eu preciso considerar o VPN (IP, login e senha).